# How to find and update specific ViewHolder for object given in notification?

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` with a `RecyclerView` of a list of employees. When the employee logs in, I receive a notification containing the employee's data. I should update the text view in the `ViewHolder` with the session status (online) and start an animation of the single `ViewHolder` related to the employee. I find the position of the employee in the `RecyclerView` but when I modify the `TextView` nothing happens...

Adapter:

```
public class EmployeesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EmployeeHolder> {

/////////////////////////////
// Private Declarations
private Employee[] employees;
private EmployeeHolder employeeHolder;
private Context context;
private EmployeeHolder[] employeeHolders;

/////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////
// Getters

public int getEmployeePosition(Employee employee) {

    for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        if (employees[i].getId() == employee.getId()) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

public EmployeeHolder[] getEmployeeHolders() {
    return employeeHolders;
}

/////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////
// Constructors

public EmployeesAdapter(Context context, Employee[] employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
    this.context = context;
    employeeHolders = new EmployeeHolder[employees.length];
}
/////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////
// Overrides

@NonNull
@Override
public EmployeeHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from( viewGroup.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.employee_card, viewGroup, false );
    employeeHolder = new EmployeeHolder( view, context );
    employeeHolders[position] = employeeHolder;
    return employeeHolder;
}

/**
 * Overrides oonBindViewHolder
 * @param holder EmployeeHolder
 * @param position int
 */
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EmployeeHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setEmployee( employees[position] );
    holder.setCard();
}

/**
 * Gets items count
 * @return int
 */
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return employees.length;
}

/////////////////////////////

}
```

EmployeeHolder:

```
public class EmployeeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

/////////////////////////////
// Private Declarations
private Employee employee;
private TextView txtEmployee;
private TextView txtPhone;
private ImageView imageView;
private TextView txtSession;
private Context context;
/////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////
// Getters

public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}
/////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////
// Setters

public void setEmployee(final Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;

}
/////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////
// Constructors

public EmployeeHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final Context context) {
    super( itemView );
    imageView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.employee_card_profile_image );
    txtEmployee = itemView.findViewById( R.id.employee_card_txt_employee);
    txtPhone = itemView.findViewById( R.id.employee_card_txt_phone );
    txtSession = itemView.findViewById( R.id.employee_card_txt_session );
    this.context = context;
}
/////////////////////////////    

/////////////////////////////
// Methods

/**
 * Sets the card with employee data
 */
public void setCard() {
    String e = employee.getLastName() + " " + employee.getFirstName();
    txtEmployee.setText( e );
    txtPhone.setText( employee.getPhone() );
    txtSession.setTextColor( employee.getSessionState().getBackgroundColor( context ) );
    txtSession.setText( employee.getSessionState().ToString( context ));

}
/////////////////////////////
}
```

Activity:

```
public class ManagementEmployeesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
EmployeesAdapter employeesAdapter;

private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            Employee employee = new Employee( intent.getBundleExtra( "employee" ) );
            int position = employeesAdapter.getEmployeePosition( employee );
            employeesAdapter.getEmployeeHolders()[position].getEmployee().setSessionState( employee.getSessionState() );
            employeesAdapter.getEmployeeHolders()[position].setCard() ;
            employeesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        // this don't work... single item don't update but if i call
        // loadEmployee(); refresh all entire list 
        // I want update single employee and start animation only on his 
        // ViewHolder

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance( this ).unregisterReceiver( receiver );
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance( this ).registerReceiver( receiver, new IntentFilter( "name_of_intent......" ) );


    loadEmployees();





}

/**
 * Load employees
 */
private void loadEmployees() {
    try {
        company.loadEmployees();
        employeesAdapter = new EmployeesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), company.getEmployees() );
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( this );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager( layoutManager );
        recyclerView.setAdapter( employeesAdapter );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Utility.message( getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage() );
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This line in `onCreateViewHolder()` is something you should not be doing: `employeeHolders[position] = employeeHolder`. The RecyclerView will re-use view holders, binding the same viewholder to different positions and different employees over the lifetime of the recyclerview.

Comment: Note also that the second argument to `onCreateViewHolder()` is `viewType`, not `position`. Chances are good that the value of that parameter is `0`, and so you are only ever filling in `employeeHolders[0]`.

Comment: Is this why the data doesn't change? Is the rest of the code correct?

Comment: every employee view holder is different or view holder is same and data is different.